# Does anyone say this is the paradox of the red heifer?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, chukas, parah-adumah

I've always understood that the *parah adumah*, the red heifer, is the quintessential *chok*, decree of the Torah, because it has the following paradox: It purifies the impure, and it impurifies the pure. Namely, the ashes of the red heifer are sprinkled upon an impure person. Upon receiving said sprinkling, they become pure, and the one doing the sprinkling becomes impure.

Now, this does seem to be what the Torah says in Numbers 19:21:

> וְהָיְתָ֥ה לָהֶ֖ם לְחֻקַּ֣ת עוֹלָ֑ם וּמַזֵּ֤ה מֵֽי־הַנִּדָּה֙ יְכַבֵּ֣ס בְּגָדָ֔יו וְהַנֹּגֵ֙עַ֙ בְּמֵ֣י הַנִּדָּ֔ה יִטְמָ֖א עַד־הָעָֽרֶב׃
>
> That shall be for them a law for all time. Further, the one who sprinkled the water of lustration shall wash those clothes; and whoever touches the water of lustration shall be impure until evening.

However, I guess I didn't read Rashi carefully, as he brings there from Yoma 14a and Niddah 9a that the word "מזה", or the one who sprinkled, isn't to be read literally. There, it means someone who *carries* the purifying waters, not for the sake of sprinkling (see Tosafos *Niddah*), becomes impure. However, the sprinkler remains pure.

While this also is a paradox, I was wondering if anyone (Tannaim, Rishonim, Achronim) actually reads the verse literally. I did see Rabbi Akiva in that *gemarra* disagrees with the Sages, but says a different paradox: If person who was sprinkled upon was impure, he will become pure. However, if they were already pure, they'll become impure. This is brought by Rabbeinu Bachaye, Numbers 19:19. However, this is different than the literal reading of the verse which I brought.

Comment: It sounds like the Gra understood that in order to sprinkle then by default they carried the water while the sprinkled it. https://www.sefaria.org/Aderet_Eliyahu%2C_Numbers.19.21?lang=bi

Comment: I agree, how can you sprinkle without moving it?

Comment: @DoubleAA see my edit